# AWS API Gateway Lambda function works with Postman but not with jquery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda (node) function that works fine when I invoke it using postman but not when I used jquery `$.ajax`.

The function is being called from a local html page using javascript/jquery.

I have the 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin' chrome plugin enabled.

The request passes the same json object using possman and jQuery.

```
{   
    "deviceid" : "ZZ-5A-04-A6-XX-YY"
}
```

I tried the following gateway request mapping templates.

1. `$input.json('$')`

   When I log the even node object I see the following line

   ```
   deviceid=ZZ-5A-04-A6-XX-YY
   ```
2. `$input.body`

   I get the error:

   > Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token

Comment: What does your jQuery.ajax request look like? Are you passing a `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Comment: How about using Lambda Proxy integration? It's much simpler. Switching won't immediately fix your problem but it will be easier to maintain and troubleshoot.

Comment: var hardobj = {
   "deviceid": "ADKNDND"
 };
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: API_URL,
 data: hardobj,
 dataType: 'json',
 headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 crossDomain: true,
 success: function (data) {getdatasuccess(data)},
 error: function(data){
 console.log("error = "+JSON.stringify(data));
 }
 });

Answer (score 1):

Solved this finally. 
In addition to using the chrome allow cross origin plugin the data object needs to be send as a string when using jquery ajax.

data: JSON.stringify(hardobj)

Hope someone else does not have to waste a week trying to figure this one out.